# How can I disable the password reset prompt at ssh login for expired password? (RHEL 6.9)

Tags: ssh, login, password, rhel6, sssd

Environment:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.9 (Santiago)
LDAP provided by Oracle Directory Server running on Solaris
```

How do I turn off the automatic change password prompt when a user logs in with an expired password? I want the login to fail with a message that the password is expired. 
It would be nice to add a message to contact our help desk also.

Currently when a user's password is found to have expired the system runs a password reset program but that does not work on our system because of our LDAP server.

I have tried changing `chpass_provider = ldap` to `chpass_provider = none` in the sssd.conf file [domain] section. But that did not work for me.

Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way is to set the account to expire as well as the password. If they occur on the same day then the user will still get the warning and be able to change their password *before* it expires, but once it does expire they will not be able to login and/or change their password.

This command will list expiration properties about the user:

```
 $ chage -l <username>
 Last password change                                    : Dec 29, 2017
 Password expires                                        : never
 Password inactive                                       : never
 Account expires                                         : never
 Minimum number of days between password change          : 0
 Maximum number of days between password change          : 99999
 Number of days of warning before password expires       : 7
```

You are also able to set properties with the `chage` command.

As for newly created users, you can modify `/etc/default/useradd` and set the `EXPIRE=` value which will set when the account expires for users created with useradd.

As far as alerting IT. You could probably pretty easily iterate through the users and run the `chage` command to see if their account is locked/expired, and generate an email.

This has some info: https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-manage-linux-password-expiry-with-the-chage-command/

Comment: Thank you. I should have mentioned that chage is not working for me. I get chage: user 'user' does not exist in /etc/passwd. If there is a configuration to make chage work with LDAP that would be awesome.

Answer (score 0):

`chage`, as already mentioned, is a good start. Also consider `/etc/login.defs` and the `PASS_*` options in it.

Further it looks like sssd is involved, in sssd.conf there are also password expiry config options (e.g `pwd_expiration_warning` or `pam_pwd_expiration_warning`).

Comment: Thank you. I will look at those `sssd.conf` options. I looked at  `/etc/login.defs` and I will look there again.